# Java equivalent of Visual Basic MidB$

Tags: java, vba, code-conversion

Is there an equivalent function in Java for MidB$?

The function returns the specified number of bytes from a string where the definition is `MidB$(String As String, Start As Long, [Length] ) As String`

It functions a bit similar to String.substring() but the length is defined in bytes.

Thanks.

Comment: In Java a String is composed of characters, not bytes. Do you really want to get the number of *bytes* or do you actually want the number of *characters*?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Yes, I actually want to retrieve the number of characters given the specified number of bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

`int bytes = str.getBytes().length;`

But this will be dependent on the character encoding of your platform.

More on [`getBytes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

```
private String MidB(String str, int start, int len) {
    byte[] bytes = str.getBytes()
    String ret = "";
    for (;start < len + start; start++)
       ret = ret + (char) bytes[start];
    return ret;
}
```

See if that works. And start won't get changed because primitives are passed by value in Java.